# How to remove a chapter from a local ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir

In a chapter of a volume I have a local ToC. I would like to remove the chapter itself from that ToC, or, if that's a good way to do that, any \chapter level division, so that only `\section`s and lower subdivision appear in it. I don't want to use `\chapter*`, as I want the chapter to appear in the ToC of the book, and to keep its numbering.

A simple example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\tableofcontents*
\section{A Section}
Some text.
\section{Another Section}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC]

Edit: Maybe the word "volume" was a bit misleading. The bigger project is only one book, an edited volume with contributions from different authors, each of them in its own file. So far I've mostly worked on the individual chapters and a shared style file, but soon I'll also have to see how I put it all together. I have a preliminary "global" ToC for the book which I created manually, eventually it would be good to replace it with something automatically generated when compiling the whole book, and this somewhat odd local ToC in one contribution, shifting which to `etoc` might indeed remove one problem in the process of glueing the book together.

Comment: `\tableofcontents*` doesn't produce a local table of contents. If you have another chapter and then further sections they will also appear in this table.

Comment: can you make your question more clear? what do you exactly want?

Comment: `\tableofcontents*` just omits `Contents` in `ToC` -- it's a special command from `memoir` that deviates from standard document classes features here

Comment: How is the bigger document constructed? Removing "all chapter" entries may work for your volume, but would certainly affect other components of the book.

Comment: So far I don't know yet how I'll "glue together" the book, I hope I'll get `combine` to work for it, but indeed one of the problems so far was this ToC which I inherited from the author without asking for it. Anyway, I still haven't really started glueing things together. The chapters of the volume live in separate files, and as long as I compile only this one file alone the ToC works fine, just that I wanted to get rid of the chapter title. Now I'll look into using `etoc` for it.

Comment: @muk.li: You need to also provide information regarding the bigger scope, as some solutions here might only work for the smaller use-case. It may be too late to salvage it in this question, but for your next one, remember that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a local ToC at section level consider loading `etoc` and use

```
\etocsettocdepth.toc{section}
\localtableofcontents*
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{section}
\localtableofcontents*
\section{A Section}
Some text.
\section{Another Section}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just looking into it. Actually the author had a ToC of up to `paragraph` level, so I changed it accordingly. I get two pages of ToC, the first page with normal inter line spacing, but the second page with double spacing.

Comment: I got it to work now, after closing the second page of the ToC with a \newpage it rendered fine. Only that I'm still getting a warning in my logfile, which doesn't really seem to make sense: `Package etoc Warning: package tocvsec2 detected and its modification of
 \tableofcontents reverted. Use \etocsettocdepth.toc as a replacement
 for the tocvsec2 toc-related commands on input line 65.`

Comment: @muk.li The strange warning will be removed from etoc version `1.08g`.

Answer (score 2):

This is only for non-`hyperref` usage. And I don't recommend it all.
Temporarily redefine `\addcontentsline` with 3 arguments to catch them within a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair and issue the `\chapter` then.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Do nothing
\chapter{My Chapter}
\endgroup
\tableofcontents*
\section{A Section}
Some text.
\section{Another Section}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```